# CPLEX opl constraints that encode compatibility

Tags: cplex, opl

The goal of the opl model below is to choose the freights with total minimum cost to fulfill all orders, I have a constraint where only compatible MaterialCategory could be allow to put on a freight. Currently the optimal solution is to use the third freight for all orders (since it's the cheapest), but with the new constraint, the 3rd freight can carry at most two orders (MaterialCategory of A, B, since C is compatible with them), what's a good way to encode the constraint?

current .mod file (model file)

```
tuple TFreightTypes {
  key string Destination;
  key string VehicleType;
  int TotalWeight;
  key string Company;
  int Cost;
};

tuple TOrders {
  key int OrderNumber;
  float Weight;
  string ClientId;
  string Destination;
  string MaterialCategory;
  int CategoryPriority;
};

{TFreightTypes}    FreightTypes = ...;
{TOrders}    Orders = ...;


dvar boolean Assignment[Orders][FreightTypes];


dexpr float objective = 
  sum(o in Orders, f in FreightTypes)
     Assignment[o][f] * f.Cost;


//choose freight with total minimum cost
minimize objective;


subject to{

  //c1: all order must be fulfilled
  forall(o in Orders)
    sum(f in FreightTypes) Assignment[o][f]==1;
    
  //c2: the order on a freight must be with compatible material type
   
}
```

.dat file (data file)

```
FreightTypes = {
    <"LONDON","Type1",20000,"SP TRANSPORTS",40000>,
    <"LONDON","Type2",20000,"SP TRANSPORTS",40000>,
    <"DURHAM","Type3",10000,"SP TRANSPORTS",30000>,

};
Orders = {
    <1,5000,"Client1","LONDON","A",0>,
    <2,1000,"Client2","DURHAM","B",1>,
    <3,2000,"Client3","LONDON","C",1>,      

};
```

Below is the compatible table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with

```
tuple TFreightTypes {
  key string Destination;
  key string VehicleType;
  int TotalWeight;
  key string Company;
  int Cost;
};

tuple TOrders {
  key int OrderNumber;
  float Weight;
  string ClientId;
  string Destination;
  string MaterialCategory;
  int CategoryPriority;
};





{TFreightTypes}    FreightTypes = ...;
{TOrders}    Orders = ...;

{string} categories={o.MaterialCategory | o in Orders};

int compat[categories][categories]=[[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,0,1]];


dvar boolean Assignment[Orders][FreightTypes];

dvar boolean categoryInFreight[categories][FreightTypes];


dexpr float objective = 
  sum(o in Orders, f in FreightTypes)
     Assignment[o][f] * f.Cost;


//choose freight with total minimum cost
minimize objective;


subject to{
  
  forall( c in categories, f in FreightTypes)
    categoryInFreight[c][f]==
    (1<=sum(o in Orders:o.MaterialCategory==c)Assignment[o][f]);

  //c1: all order must be fulfilled
  forall(o in Orders)
    sum(f in FreightTypes) Assignment[o][f]==1;
    
  //c2: the order on a freight must be with compatible material type
  forall(ordered c1,c2 in categories:compat[c1][c2]==0)
    forall(f in FreightTypes )
      categoryInFreight[c1][f]+categoryInFreight[c2][f]<=1;
   
}
```